# How to view file properties in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, file-properties

I am following along to a video on msdn's channel 9 page.

[Bob Tabor teaches C#](https://channel9.msdn.com/series/C-Fundamentals-for-Absolute-Beginners/12)

Around the 12:37 time mark, the narrator tells how to view the file properties in Visual Studio. But that is for an older edition. The problem is I added a `.txt` file to the C# project but it was not included in the `\bin\Debug` folder. How do I view the file properties window?

View the attached images:

[image: file-source]

[image: solutions-explorer]

Comment: Right click in the file -> Properties -> Copy To Output Directorey -> (Copy Always | Copy if newer)

Comment: I am unable to get to copy to output directory

Answer (score 0):

I had to reset the settings. Somehow they got messed up and the properties window was unable to be viewed.